# Using [] in class implementation, C++

Tags: c++

I have overloaded the [] operator for a data structure that I've created. I'm wanting to use the [] operator in another function in the data structure, in order to assign the value of [index+1] to [index]. How would I do this?

I've tried:

- this->[index]
- *this[index]
- &this[index]
  -[index]

Comment: Just to be clear: You want to call `operator[]` from within the class?

Comment: Yes.Ultimately, I'm wanting to implement erase(), like in the stl vector, but for a different data structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wrap `*this` into parenthesis:

```
(*this)[index]
```

Another way should be calling the operator as a function:

```
this->operator[](index)
```

Comment: Your answer seems to work for retrieval, but not for editing the actual contents of the data structure. As an example, after setting (*this)[50] to 100, the data structure still returns the original value of (*this)[50].

Comment: that's an error in your implementation.  I'm betting you aren't returning an lvalue reference, and instead returning prvalue

Comment: @CameronTylerCassidy : Then it's worth checking the implementation of `[]` operators. There should two of them, one returning reference for lvaue and one returning const reference for rvalue. It could be the case, that the one returning reference doesn't really return reference to the object within the structure.

Comment: @CameronTylerCassidy [Look at the declaration of the array operator for vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).  Are you making two overloads, not just one?  In addition, do you have one that works for `const` instances of your object, just as vector has?

Comment: Ah, I've only got a single [] operator. I've certainly done something wrong. Thank you both for all of your help!